# PHPStorm can't analyse a path from a variable?

Tags: php, phpstorm

[image: Not so awesome picture]

As you see, the first require_once gives no weak warning. The latter one does, but I don't understand why. Is there any reason why this is happening? The file exists and contains a class. If its any useful, this is the file structure:

```
-| Project
  -| Anomius
    - Anomius.php (This is the included file)
  -| Sites
    -| Foo
      - app.php (This is the file on the image)
```

Comment: Yes -- because it's a variable and value can be changed at ANY time (or can even be assigned from unknown source, e.g. DB). Use constants if so desired as PhpStorm does not track variable values.

Comment: have you tried clicking on the "more..." link? it may be more descriptive...

Comment: @LazyOne Seems like it's that. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @STTLCU Nah, that doesn't inform me a lot. It just says "Include expression is not resolved".

Comment: @STTLCU PhpStorm's "more..." links are rarely very helpful. :(

Comment: I don't use phpstorm, maybe it was different. it was worth a try ^^" Anyway, the message "Include expression is not resolved" IS QUITE CLEAR: it's saying that at this point during code analysis, the IDE can't resolve the var content and can know beforehand if the require will be successful!

Answer (score 15):

Simply disable the setting in PhpStorm which produces the warning:

In `Settings` search for 'unresolved include'
which is under `Editor` > `Inspections`; `PHP` > `General` > `Unresolved include`

and uncheck the box.

Comment: I prefer this solution, because this warning surfaced in a custom "import" function, which accepts relative paths for including classes, so one doesn't need to put dirname() and `__FILE__` everywhere, only in that function.

Answer (score 6):

It is a late answer but as of now (2021) PHPStorm can suppress the warning on a much more granular base with the comment:

```
    /** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection */
```

You can put this on statement level (right above the line in question), method level (above the method your statement is in) or on file level (on top of the file right after your `<?php` tag).

PHPStorm puts the comment in the right place for you if you use one of the quick actions.
It is obviously strongly opinionated what you prefer, and disabling the warning is still an option, but I might need the warning on a different location again where it is valid.

Answer (score 5):

By default, PHPStorm only remembers variable names, not values. So if you start typing `$ano`, it'll give you auto-completion for `$anomius`, but it doesn't know what `$anomius` actually contains.

To make PHPStorm understand where your file is, try this:

```
$anomius = "your_file.php";
/** @define "$anomius" "/absolute/path/to/your/php/file" */
require_once($anomius);
```

Comment: This is rather useless: you are using there a dynamic variable for a reason. If you declare it above, what's the point of using a variable in the first place?

Comment: Yes, it's dynamic, but at least it keeps PHPStorm happy. When the script is run, the comments are ignored anyway, so it doesn't cause any problems if the file url is different.

Comment: So your answer in nutshell: don't use a dynamic variable for require_once. 
Your answer is somehow misleading, since in this case he would just  do this: require_once('your_file.php'). Why would you put this into a variable, if you know already it's value? It's complete nonsense..

Comment: No, that's not what I said. You can use dynamic variables. The question was how to take away the warning, and the answer is: tell PHPStorm what the value is for that variable, it doesn't really matter whether the value is correct or not. But in the case of the question it happened to be correct because $anomius is static.

Comment: I have defined a constant for folder structure and use this syntax. not PS can detect files. +1

`/** @define "MY_PATH" "./abs/path/" */
define( 'MY_PATH', somefunction('...') );`